# Connect a mobile client to wallet on remote Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, mobile

I run a Bitcoin Core node on my computer and have a Windows tablet. My wallet is on the computer and I want to keep it there. Is there a way to have my tablet create a new Bitcoin address for my wallet by telling my node to do it and sending me the result, thus keeping my private keys and wallet off my tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the node's RPC API method [getnewaddress](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnewaddress) to create a new public-key pair and it will return the address.

Comment: That sounds great. Can you tell me how it's done on Windows?

Comment: You will need to write some code for this. An example in C# (for a different API method but you get the idea) can be found [here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5810/how-do-i-call-json-rpc-api-using-c). Another in C can be found [here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41122/how-to-call-json-rpc-api-from-c). Most languages have a bitcoin library that makes it very easy to call the API methods: bitcoinJ for Java, bitcoinJS for Javascript, bitcoin-ruby for Ruby, pybitcointools and pycoin for Python, etc. I am not aware of an existing tool that does this easier.

Comment: Thank you, karask. It also linked to a C# library on github, but that one looks like I would have to resync from the beginning, so I'll try your link first.